# tell sharpdevelop to use unix line endings?

Tags: sharpdevelop, line-endings

Is there an option to tell SharpDevelop (specifically version 3.2.1) to always save files in unix line endings?

I want it to also automatically convert all dos endings to unix endings when it saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops. I just missed the option the first time I looked.

tools > options > General > Load/Save ; there you will see a dropbox where you specify line endings